# <panel>.setLoading(false) doesnt remove the LoadMask

Tags: javascript, extjs, ext.net

I have a viewport. In center there is a Gridpanel wich on RowSelect has following js code:

```
var sPanel = Ext.getCmp('p_SouthPanel');
var ePanel = Ext.getCmp('p_EastPanel');

sPanel.setLoading(true);
ePanel.setLoading(true);

if (!sPanel.collapsed) {
    loadSouthTab();
}
if (!ePanel.collapsed) {
    loadEastTab();
}

sPanel.setLoading(false);
ePanel.setLoading(false);
```

this code works well except for the `setLoading(false)` part. I need to use 2 Masks because while loading i dont want to mask the grid. According to [extjs docs - setLoading()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-setLoading) my code should work as intended.
I've also tried it with

```
var mask = new Ext.LoadMask({target: Ext.getCmp('p_EastPanel'),  msg: "Loading..." });
mask.show();
<...>
mask.hide(); //(or mask.destroy())
```

same result: shows mask but doesn't hide...

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: What `loadSouthTab` and `loadEastTab` do? Are there any errors in console?

Comment: changing content of those panels - doesn't matter, they work fine - no errors and as i said everything works except hiding the mask